# How would i get a button in Android Studio to stay in place and not disappear when using different screen sizes

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm working on a chat app but i can't seem to get a button to stay in a fixed position when i run the app on a different type of phone. (It basically appears too far left or is completely cut off).

I'm completely new to android development so your probably going to have to break it down for me.:)

here's the code that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

       <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

           <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/user_name"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
                   android:text="Messages"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                   android:textSize="30sp"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/menu_popup"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                   android:drawableStart="@drawable/persistent_dots" />

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/message_new"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                   android:drawableStart="@drawable/temp_replace" />

           </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

       </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

       <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
           android:id="@+id/view_pager"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

       </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>


   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've also updated the code above to reflect the recent changes

Here's some images that show the buttons when put with different screen sizes.

[Here's the first image with a normal screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgE9r.png)

[Here's the image with a different screen size applied to the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0awyo.png)

Comment: You should put your code in nestedscrollview

Comment: What is happening here is, you have no constraints, so your views will be jumping around depending on what kind of screen density you are using.
 Check the answer below and let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either use a scrollview or a constraint view, try this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <constraintLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
       app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/user_name"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
           android:text="Messages"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="30sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"/>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/menu_popup"
           android:layout_width="30dp"
           android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
           android:drawableStart="@drawable/persistent_dots"
           android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/message_new"
           android:layout_width="30dp"
           android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
           android:drawableStart="@drawable/persistent_new_message"
           android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton" />

   </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/view_pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

 </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

 <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


 </constraintLayout>
```

Comment: that didn't seem to make any difference. I've updated the question with screenshots showing the behavior of the buttons when a normal screen is applied and when a larger screen is applied

Comment: Do you have discord or slack? I can add you there, call you and help you with that.
 Either way, try to set a constraint on the buttons

Add:
app:layout_constraintEnd="0dp"
android:layout_gravity="end"